Measure Words and Spacing
I'm trying to understand the general spacing rules for classifiers and numbers. My basic understanding is that when used for counting something, the number and classifier are separated by a space as in 학생 한 명 (1 student) or 한 과 (1 lesson), but if the number isn't really counting the number of things, then no space is used as in 일과 (lesson 1).
Is this understanding accurate?

Yes, what you said is correct, but there are also other times when you can forego spacing after a count word.
A common case is when using a numeric figure such as 1명 or 1과, etc, which is more common in Korean than in English. You can skip spacing after a figure regardless of whether it represents a quantity or order.
Also, when the count word and the noun together form a new word or idiom, you usually don't put space between them.
For example, 일시적 (일 = one, 시 = time, 적 = of a quality/characteristic) is a word on its own with the meaning of "temporary" or transient, and 백문이 불여일견 (A picture is worth more than a hundred words) is a proverb with counters 백 and 일, but you don't put space after them because they are part of an idiom.
